# What's happening?/going on?

Tags: word-choice

Let's say I'm on the phone with my girlfriend who's on her way home from a party. It's in the middle of the night. She's walking on a dark road. Suddenly she doesn't answer me. So I ask, worried for her...

What's happening? / What's going on?

Is one more natural to use than the other when being worried for someone?

Answer (score 1):

Either is fine, especially given the situation. Nobody will be examining your grammar if they are being attacked. :) Alternately, you could ask, "XXXX, are you ok?"

Comment: Yeah, if you're worried, "Are you OK?" seems a more natural question, and suggests that you are concerned about them rather than just curious. "What's happening?" and "What's going on?" could be asked in a wide variety of situations, some entirely neutral, or even if the person you're talking to says "Wow, that's amazing!"